# ORDER BY on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I need a query that will give me the result that is either (a) the highest price or (b) the one with the oldest timestamp.  In all cases, price should trump timestamp (ie if a record has a really old timestamp by higher price than all others, it should always return the record with the highest price)

Here are a few scenarios:

```
id | price | date
1 | 5 | 2012-02-20 08:59:06
2 | 5 | 2012-02-20 09:59:06
3 | 7 | 2012-02-20 10:59:06
```

Should return id 3 because it is highest price

```
id | price | date
1 | 5 | 2012-02-20 08:59:06
2 | 5 | 2012-02-20 09:59:06
3 | 5 | 2012-02-20 10:59:06
```

should return id 1 since it is the oldest

In my current query i am doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price, date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately this query is not working how i've outlined it above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you have shown two identical data sets, and request different results.  Do you intend to have 2 different queries? if not, which is the correct result?

Comment: i see no difference in your datasets hence it's rather difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve... :)

Comment: why should the 2nd example return id 1? You mentioned that price should always beat timestamp.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm having trouble determining precisely what you are after, however it sounds like you are looking for the oldest timestamp for the highest price, and so the following should suffice

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    price DESC,   // Favour the highest price
    date ASC      // Now get the one with oldest date at this price
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that works despite my unclear explanation of the problem.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understand your question, try this

```
SELECT 
    p.*
FROM table p
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM table)
    OR date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM table)
```